# Why does file and folder icons disappear when I select vscode-icons extension as my preferred File Icon Theme in Visual Studio Code?

Tags: visual-studio-code

I have installed **vscode-icons** extension. And set this as my preferred File-Icon Theme using **File** -> **Preferences** option in Visual Studio Code. All folders and files icons disappear. The extension is installed properly and I could see all the icons in the installed extension folder.
But when I switch back to **Set(Visual Studio Code) theme**, all the folder and file icons are visible. I have tried all possible options like install and uninstalling packages, libraries, extensions and VS Code itself. Please find below screen shot,
[image]

Comment: I’m voting to close this question because this is rather a bug report and should be posted as such in the vscode repo.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I am able to see folder and file icons after installing one more alternative extension called **file-icons.file-icons**.

Earlier I tried at least 2 extensions. But to my surprise, none of them worked. So I assumed that, something wrong in the VS Code.